# Build JSON directory list

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have been using arrays to do this and then using json_encode, but I have a problem that I need to use multidimensional arrays to build my JSON string correctly.

The problem with this is memory. As you might imagine, having an array for every single file in a directory, meaning you have hundreds of arrays inside one array, isn't exactly cheap on memory.

My question is, is there a different way? I have the following array structure:

`array(array("key" => "value"),array("key" => "value"))`

Comment: What's your final goal? You may not need to keep everything in memory, and construct your json iteratively therefore "recycling" your memory.

Comment: I have to be able to build a JSON string that basicly has every single file in the directory, but the filenames need to be a value of the key "src". Basicly, what I'm trying to make is a media player that reads the files it needs from that JSON string. I'm using the Projekktor library for that, but it requires the "src" key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not modify the following code, such that the name attribute is renamed to src?
I guess you'd have no need for the size attribute either.

```
<?php
class mFile
{
    public $name, $time, $size;
}

foreach (glob("*.*") as $curFilename)
{
    $curFileObj = new mFile;
    $curFileObj->name = $curFilename;
    $curFileObj->time = date("d/m/Y - H:i", filectime($curFilename));
    $curFileObj->size = filesize($curFilename);
    $fileArray[] = $curFileObj;
}
printf("%s", json_encode($fileArray));
?>
```

**EDIT**: sample output

[{"name":"001-deleteMe.html","time":"26/09/2012 - 00:09","size":15062},{"name":"001-test.html","time":"18/10/2012 - 04:29","size":2981},{"name":"001.html","time":"02/10/2012 - 01:26","size":2596}]

Comment: Creating an object, not a bad idea. I'll try this out, thanks. My only problem is though, I would like to randomize the order in the JSON string. I've been shuffling the arrays, but this won't work with this, correct?

Comment: No worries, an object seemed like the clear choice to me. Well, it returns an array of objects. I don't see any reason you couldn't do either (a) shuffle the array in javascript or (b) create an array of indexes. Then shuffle that. Eg, if 10 items returned, create an array with elements having values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Then just shuffle that array. Once done, just step through it. Random play-order, guaranteed not to repeat a file until they've all been played.

Comment: Alright. However, it doesn't seem to print it at all. The print doesn't print anything, and it's not running out of memory: I can do echo's after the printf. I can `print_r` the fileArray, and it displays fine, it just doesn't output anything when encoded.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds odd. I'm using php 5.3.1.0 on windows, and I forget which version under linux. Both run the script (or a similar version of it, in the case of linux) just fine here. I've only tried it with 281 files though, perhaps that's an issue. For clarity, I see you've mixed `print` and `printf` in your comment. I'm assuming you mean `printf`, right? (not to confuse that with your use of print_r, which is an entirely different beast, of course)

Comment: Yeah I mean `printf` ;) And I currently have about 200 files in the directory, so that shouldn't be the problem. Running PHP 5.5.1 on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Using `json_last_error()` I was able to figure out that it's throwing a malformed UTF-8 character(s) error. Short snippet of `print_f($fileArray)`: `( [0] => mFile Object ( [src] => audio/More - More audio.mp3 ) [1] => mFile Object ( [src] => audio/Even more - audio file 2.mp3 ))` - is it the `audio/More` and `audio/Even more` that's causing the issue?

Comment: Ahhh! Yup, I reckon that's it. I notice that although I printf the date using the `d/m/Y` format, in order to get 26/09/2012, that the actual JSON reads `{"name":"001-deleteMe.html","time":"26\/09\/2012 - 00:09","size":15062}` - notice the \ escaped slashes. Not sure which funtion would fix that. Perhaps `addslashes`. I also notice there's a second input var ($options) for json_encode. You can add a flag that tells it how to output the string. Perhaps my installs have the important flags specified by default, while yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1['key1'] = "value1";
$array2['key2'] = "value2";
$array3['key3'] = "value3";

$finalarray = array($array1, $array2 , $array3);

var_dump($finalarray);
```

result:
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key1' => string 'value1' (length=6)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key2' => string 'value2' (length=6)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'key3' => string 'value3' (length=6)